# Cómo puedo cerrar una actividad, no me funciona el finish()

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Quiero pasar de una actividad a otra y cerrar mi actividad anterior, que no se quede en segundo plano, pero le doy finish() y no sirve

Que puedo hacer ?
Cuando le doy atrás si vuelve a la actividad que quiero, pero esta se queda en ejecución, necesito que se acabe la actividad.

GRACIAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es Android, supongo. ¿Por qué no pusiste la etiqueta principal?

Comment: Hola Sebas, como sabes que se queda en segundo plano, explica esto

Comment: Tengo una función que se ejecuta, es un juego y cuando le doy atrás, vuelve a la actividad anterior, pero sigue ejecutandose el juego